# Partial derivatives of $u = \frac{\cos x^2}{y}$ (1st and 2nd)

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

So there's

$$u = \frac{\cos(x^2)}{y}$$

I got the following:

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = -\frac{2x\sin(x^2)}{y}$$

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{}y} = -\frac{\cos(x^2)}{y^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{y^2}} = 2\frac{\cos(x^2)}{y^3}$$

I am a bit confused with calculus of $\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial x^2}$

Comment: Just the chain rule $y$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{-2x \sin x^2}{y} \right) \\
&= -\frac{2}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x \sin x^2\right)
\end{align}
Now the problem becomes an exercise in the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is independent, $y$ is constant when computing $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= -\frac{2}{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x \sin(x^2))\\
&= -\frac{2}{y} (\sin(x^2) + 2x\cos(x^2)).
\end{align}
$$